# Ambigous error c# / sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

can someone please tell me why i am getting an error with this code ?

```
 SqlCommand scGetClaimedDetails = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT SUM(isclaimable) as claimable, SUM(isclaimed) as claimed,SUM(total) as total from" +
    " ( SELECT CASE WHEN claimed = 'Y' THEN inv_amt *.45 END as isclaimed, (inv_amt *.45) as inclaimable, inv_amt as total from invasset" +
    " INNER JOIN Invoice ON invoice.invoice = invasset.invoice WHERE invasset.asset_no = @AssetNumber ) as D2", DataAccess.AssetConnection);
```

Comment: And what is that error? Post it please.

Comment: Not unless you tell us what the error _is_.  Also, format your code to actually be readable.  It's a _lot_ easier to spot problems in code when it's readable.

Comment: The error isn't ambiguous, the column is. You have the same column-name from two different sources. You need to specify which one.

Answer (score 1):

In subquery specifiy where is inv_amt column coming from (is it invoice.inv_amt or invasset.inv_amt)

Comment: im not missing a from table as this is a sub query

Comment: I know you are not missing the "from" table. Inside the subquery, in select list you have column inv_amt which exists with that same name in tables invoice and invasset, you have to specify whether you meant invoice.inv_amt or invasset.inv_amt, replace "inv_amt" with "invoice.inv_amt" or "invasset.inv_amt".

Answer (score 1):

> ambigous column name inv_amt

It seams like the two tables `invasset` and `Invoice` both contains the column `inv_amt`, You have to reference it to an alias in the inner `SELECT` statement, something like: `invoice.inv_amt` or `invasset.inv_amt`:

```
SELECT SUM(isclaimable) as claimable, SUM(isclaimed) as claimed, 
       SUM(total) as total 
FROM
( 
   SELECT CASE WHEN claimed = 'Y' THEN invoice.inv_amt *.45 END as isclaimed, 
   (inv_amt *.45) as  inclaimable, inv_amt as total 
   from invasset INNER JOIN Invoice  ON invoice.invoice = invasset.invoice 
   WHERE invasset.asset_no = @AssetNumber 
) as D2
```

Answer (score 0):

When I format your code to be human-readable...

```
SqlCommand scGetClaimedDetails = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT
         SUM(isclaimable) AS claimable,
         SUM(isclaimed) AS claimed,
         SUM(total) AS total
     FROM
         (SELECT
              CASE WHEN claimed = 'Y' THEN inv_amt *.45 END AS isclaimed,
              (inv_amt *.45) AS inclaimable,
              inv_amt AS total
          FROM
              invasset
              INNER JOIN Invoice ON invoice.invoice = invasset.invoice
          WHERE
              invasset.asset_no = @AssetNumber) AS D2",
    DataAccess.AssetConnection);
```

I can't help but notice that your outer `SELECT` is looking for a column called `isclaimable` while your inner `SELECT` is returning a column called `inclaimable`.  There's a typo in your code.

**Edit:** In response to your comment on the question, which tables contain the field `inv_amt`?  Clearly you're referencing two tables which have it.  Since the only tables you're referencing are `invasset` and `Invoice` then clearly both of those tables have a column named `inv_amt`.  You'll have to specify which one you want in your query.

So instead of:

```
`inv_amt AS total`
```

You'd want something like:

```
`invasset.inv_amt AS total`
```

(Assuming that's the table you want, otherwise use the other table.)